# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) not working

Tags: php, forms, button, post, submit

I know there are cases on this, however I tried their method, but it didn't work for me.

**Here is the code for isset:** I tried placing this statement before `<head>` tag and within `<body>` tag but don't think it made a difference. **This code resides in the same php file as the the submit button.**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    echo "testing";
    exit();
}?>
```

**Here is the form & submit button within form**

```
<form name="createCaseForm" method = "post" action = "<?php echo url_mgt::getActionURL(); ?>" id="case-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
    <td colspan="1"><button style="float:right;" name="action" type="submit" value="create_case_submit">Submit</button></td>
    ...
</form>
```

I'm not sure if using `<button>` instead `<input>` of would make a difference. I also did if(count($_POST) > 0) and it didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I run the file, it doesn't echo "testing", but instead went straight to the next page. My apologies if it's just a minor matter, but I tried methods posted in forums, but none seems to work.

I've tried to do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) == 0) {
  echo "Testing";
} else {
    echo "Testing2";
}
```

It displays testing when the page is being loaded, however when i click on the submit button, I was hoping to see testing2 being printed. Am i right to say that after clicking the submit button, the page would not reload twice? So there is no way to check if the submit button is being posted?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as above, **if(isset($_POST['submit'])) not working** when submitting a form. Setting the name to *action* didn't work for me. The solution was to assigned the **submit** to the *name* field of my form's input element. Here I present a MCVE tested in Firefox.

Kf

### index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="learnphp.php" method="post">

      <table border="0">

    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username" size="30"/></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
      <td>City</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text" name="cityaddress" size="30"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input id="radio1" type="radio"  name="selector"
             value="op1" /> </td>
      <td><input id="radio2" type="radio"  name="selector"
             value="op2" /> </td>         
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
      name="submit" value="SubmiT"/></td>
    </tr>

      </table>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

### learnphp.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Information Gathered</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
       echo "<p>Data processed \"NOW\"</p>";      

       echo "<p>Let's observe: </p>";

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           echo "submit set<br>";
           echo "Submit value=" . $_POST['submit'] . "<br>";
       }
       else echo "ERROR submit not set<br>";

       if(isset($_POST['selector'])){
           echo "Selecter set<br>";
           echo "Radial selection value=" . $_POST['selector'] . "<br>";
       }
       else echo "ERROR Selector not set<br>";

    echo "</br>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Output:

> Data processed "NOW"
>
> Let's observe:
>   submit set
>   Submit value=SubmiT
>   Selecter set
>   Radial selection value=op2

Answer (score 0):

You need a form field named `action`

```
<input type="text" name="action"/>
```

Also, make sure that `url_mgt::getActionURL()` is outputting the correct URL to submit to

Comment: yes, getActionURL() is redirecting my pages correctly. What do you mean by form field named action? name="action" is declared in my submit button in the `<button>` tag. Does it not work because it's on the same page?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual POST data using something like Firebug or Chrome inspector? Is the button element being submitted?

Comment: in another file where the form redirects to (action.php), I'm able to do this $action = $_POST['action']; and the value works. However, i'm not able to do the isset($_post) stuff within the same page. The codes above all reside in the same php file (create_case.php). Hence i'm not sure if the isset() function is not working because it's in the same file, or if it does not matter at all.

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you POST your form, it's a brand new call.