# How to Initiate the Submit button function

Tags: php, html, submit

I'm currently developing a form for web scraping activities, how can i initiate the submit button function using isSet?

here's my code:

```
<form id="startWeb" name="startWeb" method="post" action="webcrawlBM_process.php">
<input type="button" id="startCrawl" action="submit" value="Mula Mengikis" class="gradient-background" onClick="submitForm();" style="width: 230px" />
```

when the user clicks on submit, a javascript function will initiate.

```
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('startWeb').action = action;
    document.getElementById('startWeb').submit();
    alert('Data anda telah disimpan!  Anda akan dihalakan kembali ke halaman utama.');
    window.location = 'index.php';
}
```

here's my isset function that is problematic.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $webcrawl = new WebCrawlerBM($_POST['target_url']);

```
if ($webcrawl->WebCrawlerBM($_POST['target_url'])) {
if ($webcrawl->submitForm()) {
    $webcrawl->set_webpage($url);
    $webcrawl->set_makefile($text); 
    $webcrawl->set_writefile($filename);
    $webcrawl->set_striphtmltags($text);

    echo "Your action had been completed successfully.  <br>";
}
```

The situation is that when i click, nothing happens.

Comment: its supposed to be `name="submit"` attribute in your input button for your `isset($_POST['submit'])` to work, `action=""` attributes are for `<form>` tags

Comment: give a name to your button .....as @Ghost has mentioned...you can give the name to the button just like submit or mybt and then use that name with isset

Comment: @Ghost i gave the button a name, & it it still unresponsive. perhaps do i need to put the declaration of isset somewhere else? is it before the head, or within the body section?

Comment: @OpenSource i also changed the submit in isset($_POST['submit']) to another name. maybe the javascript is misplaced?

Comment: i found this post. it's what i'm trying to deliver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691331/ifisset-postsubmit-not-working